# Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e07'

Tags: asp-classic

I'm trying to figure out this error message and I'm not sure what exactly is the issue.

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e07'

[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

```
tmpsql = "select EVE_GID from Events where EVE_DATED = '" & request("EVE_DATED") & "' and 
EVE_STARTTIME = '" & request("EVE_DATED") & " " & request("EVE_STARTTIME") & "'"

rs.Open tmpsql,MM_editConnection
```

I think it has to do with my quotes but I'm not sure. Can anyone give me a clue on why I keep getting this error message? The data is hosted on a SQL server.

O yes 
     EVE_GID = int     EVE_DATED = datetime     EVE_STARTTIME = datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spit out your SQL statement before you execute it an see what you're getting:

```
tmpsql = "select EVE_GID from Events where EVE_DATED = '" & request("EVE_DATED") & "' and 
EVE_STARTTIME = '" & request("EVE_DATED") & " " & request("EVE_STARTTIME") & "'"

response.write(tmpsql)

'rs.Open tmpsql,MM_editConnection <-- comment out this
```

Comment: (I picked the 21st and 6:30 for the test)Came back as: select EVE_GID from Events where EVE_DATED = '9/21/2011' and EVE_STARTTIME = '9/21/2011 6:30'

Comment: OK - take a look at your table schema and see if this query makes sense.

Comment: Ok I checked and everything looks like its formatted correctly. EVE_DATED = 2009-12-02 00:00:00.000 and EVE_STARTTIME = 2009-12-02 06:30:00.000

Comment: ok well looking through everything this could be more than just the code. I took over this app a month ago so I don't know too much about. I'll talk to my DB admin about this next week. That little tip is helpful =)